# esp8266 sending synchronized https requests (using WiFiClientSecure) without delay

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-esp8266

i am trying to send a synchronized request to https server with esp8266 and i am using httpbin.org for testing purpose and i want to synchronize the requests. i mean **how to not sending request until the previous is recieved and without using ***delay***?**

**by comparing code (below) and result (below) you can see that `httpsClient.readString()` returns empty result from time to time. why? how to explain that? and how to fix that or get around it?**

code and result are bellow. please help.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
//i cut wifi ssid and pswrd declaration to shorten the question
const char *host = "httpbin.org"; //Domain to Server
String path = "/post"; //Path of Server
const int httpsPort = 443; //HTTPS PORT (default: 443)

WiFiClientSecure httpsClient;
String response;

void setup() {
  //i cut wifi set up declaration to shorten the question
  httpsClient.setInsecure();
  if(httpsClient.connect(host, httpsPort)){
    Serial.println("Connected to "+String(host));
    }else
    Serial.println("error connecting");
}


void loop() {

  httpsClient.print(String("POST ") + "/response-headers" + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
      "Host: " + "httpbin.com\r\n"+
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +         
      "Content-Length: 13\r\n\r\n" +
      "say=Hi&to=Sam\r\n");
      
 while(httpsClient.available()) {
    response = httpsClient.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(response);
 }
 
 Serial.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 16:20:01 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 68

Connection: keep-alive

Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true



{
  "Content-Length": "68", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 16:20:01 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 68

Connection: keep-alive

Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true



{
  "Content-Length": "68", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 16:20:01 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 68

Connection: keep-alive

Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true



{
  "Content-Length": "68", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
---------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 16:20:02 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 68

Connection: keep-alive

Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true



{
  "Content-Length": "68", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 16:26:19 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 68

Connection: keep-alive

Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true



{
  "Content-Length": "68", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
and so on.....
```

Comment: You send the request then immediately check for a response. Try waiting a bit before trying to read. Or, loop until some data is available: `while (!httpsClient.available()) { delay(100); }`

Comment: use `do {} while ()` to start with readStringUntil

Comment: thank you @JohnnyMopp while loop worked now and it is good .   i tried that solution before but something was going wrong and it get stuck in loop. that is why i asked.

Comment: You could add a counter and break out of the loop after a certain number of tries: `int retries = 0; while (retries++ < 10 && !httpsClient.available()) { delay(100); }`

Comment: thank you i will try it